# Flutter BottomNavigationBar with showModalBottomSheet like PayPal

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I'm trying to build a bottom bar with center button like this:

[image: paypal app]

but I can't show the bottom sheet as expected.

First try: `showModalBottomSheet` -> overlays bottomnavbar, tried adding margin with transparent background and no opacity but I can't tap navigation bar anymore to close it

Second try: `showBottomSheet` -> error `The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:No Scaffold widget found.` So I tried using `scaffoldKey` but I couldn't close the sheet pressing outside or any other `BottomNavigationBarItem`, only scrolling down.

How can I build the same dialog and behavior as PayPal?

Comment: solved using useRootNavigator true

Comment: hi i have same problem with this, can i know how you fix this with full code ?
i have set useRootNavigator true but it doesn't work, showModalBottomSheet when appear it still cover the bottomNavigationBar

Comment: @rooxane.mac sorry I don't have that part of the code anymore and I can't remember how I did